# Accessing a MAPI folder in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, outlook, mapi

I have the following C# Code

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application myApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook._NameSpace mapiNameSpace = myApp.GetNamespace("MAPI");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MAPIFolder myInbox = mapiNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
```

With it I can access my Inbox.  Great!  Now I need to access the CTPend folder that lives on the same level as the Inbox.  I cannot figure out how to do that. I keep cycling through things I can call that send me folders but won't let me pick one and objects that specify a folder, with no method that generates one.  Help.

Answer (score 2):

Go up one level to the Inbox folder, then to that folder:

```
anotherfolder = myInbox.Parent.Folders("CTPend")
```

or use the parent store and drill down to that folder starting with the root folder of that store:

```
store = myInbox.Store
anotherfolder = store.GetRootFolder.Folders("CTPend")
```